# Increment a Varchar

Tags: sql

Hi All So I have the below data table

```
SERIAL No START SERIAL No END
C04X000001        C04X000200
A04X000201        A04X005200
A04X005201        A04X005800
B04X005801        B04X006200
D04X006201        D04X006450
E05X088681        E05X088880
E05X088881        E05X089000
```

What i need to be able to do is to inset all the serials between the two numbers into a table.

E.G

```
C04X000001,C04X000002,C04X000003,04X000004,C04X000005 ..... C04X000199, C04X000200
```

The problem i have is the varying data lengths.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Using strings to represent numbers is usually a bad idea. I would suggest keeping the string part and the number part in 2 different columns if possible.

Comment: Where does the number portion of your serial number begin and the alpha-numeric end?  Is it a fixed location?  (i.e. Does the number always start at the 5th character from the left?)

Comment: The data is not my own, all are serial numbers for products, Looking they are all Letter, Number, Number Letter - (A11X) Then a string of numbers.

Comment: What database are you working with?

Comment: @user3224101 Please include the DBMS you are using (e.g.: SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.), as the solution will be different across different products/versions.